# How to fix bootstrap dropdown menu buy when using rtl

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm coding a page using html dir="rtl", but unfortunately it messed up with my bootstrap drop down menu positioning. any idea how to fix it?

```
<html dir="rtl">
<div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

[link to the code](http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/229/). don't forget to wrap the code with html dir="rtl".

image:
http://oi58.tinypic.com/zl69ad.jpg

Comment: *it messed up with my bootstrap drop down menu positioning* what's exactly messed up? can you create a [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstarte the issue? and also tell us what's the expected result.. as it stand your question is a guessing game

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have added a link and an image to the question.

Comment: I don't know of bootstrap supporting RTL. You may need another library. google for bootstrap rtl, looks like there are a few.

Comment: the real problem is hosting pictures on tinypic